# Create PHP Breadcrumbs from query string

Tags: php

Im creating a breacrumb function for our website but run into a small problem.
When executing the breadcrumb function the first child is empty.

I can hide it with css. But i want it to be perfect.

```
function breadcrumbs() {

// Define urls
$home_url    = URL;
$current_url = http:/example.com/index.php?folder=Salestijgers&sub_dir_1=Naamloze%20map%202&sub_dir_2=Afbeeldingen%20website;
$all_query   = $_GET;
$count_query = count( $all_query );
$last_query  = str_replace( '%20', ' ', substr( $current_url, strrpos( $current_url, '=' ) + 1 ) ); // Last query

$breadcrumbs = array(
    $current_url
);

for( $i = 2; $i <= $count_query; $i++ ) {

    $last = substr( $current_url, strrpos( $current_url, '&' ) ); // Last query
    $new_url = str_replace( $last, '', $current_url );
    $current_url = $new_url;

    $breadcrumbs[] = $current_url;
}

krsort( $breadcrumbs );
$count_links = count( $breadcrumbs );
$current_page= "<li order=\"last-child\"><span>$last_query</span></li>";

for( $i = $count_links; $i >= 1; $i-- ) {

    $title = str_replace( '%20', ' ', substr( $breadcrumbs[$i], strrpos( $breadcrumbs[$i], '=' ) + 1 ) );

    $url .= "<li order=\"$i\"><a order=\"$i\" href=\"{$breadcrumbs[$i]}\" title=\"$title\">$title</a><i class=\"fa fa-angle-right\"></i></li>";
}

if( isset( $_GET['folder'] ) ) {
    return $url . $current_page;
} else {
    return "<li class=\"dont-hide\"><span>Mijn bestanden</span></li>";
}
}
```

I want the output as following

**Mijn bestanden** >> **Salestijgers** >> **Naamloze map** >> Afbeeldingen Website

*Bold are links, not bold is current page

I hope you guys can help me out!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `$breadcrumbs = array_filter( $breadcrumbs );` to filter out empty entries.